# Setting Kanthal Wire

Tags: temperature, heat

I have a furnace that is heated by a small Kanthal coil. The core is formed by wrapping the Kanthal wire around an alumina cylinder. One problem we have had is that the wire springs out of shape after it is wrapped. We temporarily solved the problem by gluing the wire as we wrap the core with super glue; however, even after the glue cures there is enough spring force to break free from the ceramic. Is there a way to cure the Kanthal wire to help it retains its shape?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is pure materials science

Comment: hehehe, no, it's applied materials science :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try annealing the wire (see the manufacturer for recommendations on the temperature, but the idea is to heat it to a certain temperature range and allow it to cool slowly, which makes the wire softer). This can be done by putting current through the wire or with external heating.

Or buy annealed wire, but winding it may work-harden it.

Answer (score 1):

Wind it round a smaller diameter cylinder and let it spring back. Then transfer it to the alumina cylinder. Ideally, after springback its diameter is slightly too small to fit : untwist it a little, insert cylinder, and release.

You may find its properties change with heating as Spehro suggests.